# How can I specify both section and row in the indexPath call to my array?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsindexpath

Previously, I was populating my TableView by using this code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath:
        indexPath) as CustomTableViewCell

    let entry = entries[indexPath.row]
    cell.entryLabel!.text = entry.labelOne
    cell.entryDayLabel!.text = entry.day
    cell.entryDateLabel!.text = entry.date

    return cell
}
```

I've since added sections to my Table, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to specify both the section and the row in this call to my array.

I've tried

```
let entry = entries[indexPath.section]
```

and I've tried

```
let entry = entries[indexPath.row + indexPath.section]
```

But neither work correctly.

Is there a proper way to do this that I'm missing? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
indexPath.section
```

will return the current section.

What you usually want to do then, is add some conditional logic like:

```
if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
    entry = entries[indexPath.row]
}
else if(indexPath.section == 1)
{
    entry = whateverDataSource[indexPath.row]
}
```

Are you using two different tables and/or cell types for your sections?

Comment: I have all of my data stored in one Core Data model, with "section" being one of the attributes. The data is sorted into sections via setting the sectionNameKeyPath in an NSFetchedResultsController